# iOS push notifications not being delivered at all

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am using Parse with a WebKitUI app. It is working and all the devices are registering for push notifications, I have over 100 devices now registered.However, it says "0 Users." Also whenever I send a push NO ONE receives it and they all say "opened by 0 people, etc."

What is wrong??

Comment: Are you using a development certificate in production?

Comment: nope, i am using a production certificate

Comment: have you found a solutions for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check Settings of your Parse app, in push section have you uploaded Push Certificates?

Also, to confirm if your devices have registered, check Installation class in Parse App which has device token and installation ID.

If installation class in not populated properly, check method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in your app delegate.

Parse had good documentation on this, https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#setup/iOS